# how to convert xml file to text file using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, text, tags, key

I want to convert XML file to text file using XSLT.

I want to extract below values from posted code:

> patient in old age.patient has another cancer or one of his family
>   has cancer.     patient comes from African-Caribbean and African
>   descent than in men of Asian  descen which prostate cancer is common.
>   obesity recent research suggests that there may be a link between
>   obesity and prostate cancer.

```
    <event>
      <date key="time:timestamp" value="2018-02-04T19:16:55.290-0500"/>
      <string key="concept:name" value="history"/>
      <string key="lifecycle:transition" value="start"/>
      <string key="lifecycle:instance" value="9.1"/>
      <string key="org:resource" value="PA-014e485a-16c6-4cf5-9ade-cdf6f17c69bb"/>
      <string key="history2" value="patient in old age"/>
      <string key="history1" value="patient has another cancer or one of his family has cancer"/>
      <string key="history3" value="patient comes from African-Caribbean and African descent than in men of Asian  descen which prostate cancer is common"/>
      <string key="history4" value="obesity recent research suggests that there may be a link between obesity and prostate cancer"/>
    </event>
```

Comment: :-)  It's an interesting task, but it will probably be considered too broad, too big of a question here.  At this point, it seems you want to learn all about xsl.  That isn't accepted here as a question.....   can you have a try first and then ask about a specific problem you run into?

Comment: If you really don't know any xsl, I would start here:  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog .  (old-school but useful)

Comment: Att  the very least you need to tell us how far you got, and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
<xsl:template match="event">
    <xsl:value-of select="descendant-or-self::string[starts-with(@key, 'history')]/@value" separator=". "/>
    <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

See Transformation at http://xsltransform.net/aiwQ3v

Updated Transformation for question with namespace http://xsltransform.net/6q1R79D/1

Comment: Explain us that what issue you got so that we can help you on this.

Comment: i want to convert this from xml to text using xstl.

Comment: The code that you have posted did not work. Please help me

Comment: I have added transformation and it run perfectly see transformation at [http://xsltransform.net/aiwQ3v](http://xsltransform.net/aiwQ3v)

Comment: I have added the complete code Please help 
http://xsltransform.net/6q1R79D

Comment: I have updated answer at [http://xsltransform.net/6q1R79D/1](http://xsltransform.net/6q1R79D/1). Issue is occuring due to namespace that is define on your xml.

Comment: can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: you can accept it by clicking check mark beside the answer see details at [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)